# AS3 Keyboard Control

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, keyboard-events

I've got an as3 function that controls a movie clip with the keyboard:

package 
{

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.events.Event;

public class Main_Character_Two extends MovieClip
{
    var vx:int;
    var vy:int;

    public function Main_Character_Two()
    {
        init();
    }
    function init():void
    {
        //initialize variables
        vx = 0;
        vy = 0;

        //Add event listeners
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onKeyUp);
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
    }
    function onKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void
    {
        if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT)
        {
            vx = -5;
        }
        else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT)
        {
            vx = 5;
        }
        else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.UP)
        {
            vy = -5;
        }
        else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN)
        {
            vy = 5;
        }
    }
    function onKeyUp(event:KeyboardEvent):void
    {
        if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT || event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT)
        {
            vx = 0;
        }
        else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN || event.keyCode == Keyboard.UP)
        {
            vy = 0;
        }
    }
    function onEnterFrame(event:Event):void
    {
        //Move the player
        player.x += vx;
        player.y += vy;
    }
}
```

}

This works ok but the main problem is that when you press the right key (and hold it down) then press the left key, the character will move to the left but when you release the left key (with the right key still held down) the character just stops. How can I make it so the character starts moving to the right again in this situation (if Im still holding the right key after Ive released the left key)

Thanks

Comment: good question.. but why do you need this functionality if you are only moving 10px every time a key is pressed not when it is being held down? Are you missing an onEnterFrame event listener?

Comment: I think this might be a limitation in the flash player itself.

Comment: @Tim Joyce I initially posted the wrong code example, see the above code for the correct version, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put your 'player' positioning code into an `Event.ENTER_FRAME` loop and use `KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN` and `KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP` to set booleans and position the player in the loop like:

```
var leftIsPressed:Boolean = false;
var rightIsPressed:Boolean = false;
var upIsPressed:Boolean = false;
var downIsPressed:Boolean = false;
var speed:Number = 5;
var vx:Number = 0;
var vy:Number = 0;

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUpHandler);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler);

function keyDownHandler(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
    switch(e.keyCode) {
        case Keyboard.LEFT : leftIsPressed = true; break;
        case Keyboard.RIGHT : rightIsPressed = true; break;
        case Keyboard.UP : upIsPressed = true; break;
        case Keyboard.DOWN : downIsPressed = true; break;
    }
}

function keyUpHandler(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
    switch(e.keyCode) {
        case Keyboard.LEFT : leftIsPressed = false; break;
        case Keyboard.RIGHT : rightIsPressed = false; break;
        case Keyboard.UP : upIsPressed = false; break;
        case Keyboard.DOWN : downIsPressed = false; break;
    }
}

function enterFrameHandler(e:Event):void {
    vx = -int(leftIsPressed)*speed + int(rightIsPressed)*speed;
    vy = -int(upIsPressed)*speed + int(downIsPressed)*speed;
    player.x += vx;
    player.y += vy;
}
```

[EDIT] Added a more detailed example.

Of course in this case, if both left and right keys are pressed, this would result in a `0` offset.

Comment: That would be ok of both the left and right key are both held down and the offset is 0 however the character would still need to move diagonally if both the left/right and up/down keys were held, would that still work?

Comment: Similarly, you would have a 'yOffset' for 'upKeyIsDown' and 'downKeyIsDown' that would set the 'y' position for the player. Then, for example, if you pressed left and up, the xOffset would be -10 and the yOffset would be -10 -- moving the player diagonally. Each frame the player position will update until you release the keys.

Comment: Would you mind providing a full working example for this? Thanks

Comment: Thanks Corey, this does exactly what I initially asked for. One issue still remains however. In other flash games I've noticed that if you press/hold the right arrow then press/hold the left arrow the character will initially move right but then move left when the left arrow is pressed. If you then release the left arrow the character will start moving to the right again. Any ideas on how to get that type of functionality here?

Comment: You could track the order in which the keys are pressed and give priority to the last key pressed if it's the opposite key.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to `KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP` to determine when a key has been released, so you can track which keys are being held.

Answer (score 0):

The `KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN` event is only fired when a key goes from being in the "up" state to being in the "down" state, so your character stops after you lift your finger from the LEFT key because no new `KEY_DOWN` event has been triggered that would cause the character to move.

You might be able to accomplish what you're after by adding a `KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP` event that checks to see if any of the other arrow keys are being held down when the event fires, but you'd probably need to refactor your current code to avoid repeating yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Understanding this phenomenon requires a basic understanding of the Event model, which keyboard input is based upon. It works differently in AS3 than it does in AS2.

When you press a key, an event is fired to call a function - but it is only fired *once*, when the key is pressed. The event handlers don't check whether the key is held down. (Try adding 5 to your object's x/y value instead of your vx in your onKeyDown function; you'll find that your character only moves when you press a key, not while you hold it.)

Similarly, when you released a key, an event is fired to call a function - but it is only fired once, when the key is actively released. No events are fired when the key is just sitting there.

Building upon this...can you find the source of your current problem?

```
function onKeyUp(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT || event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT)
    {
        vx = 0;
    }
    else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN || event.keyCode == Keyboard.UP)
    {
        vy = 0;
    }
}
```

If you didn't find it, it's this block.

```
    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT || event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT)
    {
        vx = 0;
    }
```

This statement tells your program to set velocity equal to zero if either the right or the left keys are pressed. However, since Flash *only checks for a keypress when you first press the key*, holding down a key will not trigger your onKeyDown function. Hence, if you hold both left and right, and let one go, you're setting your velocity to zero.

Corey has the logical solution here, and there are some other reasons that you'll want to use a toggled boolean value to check keyboard input (the main reason is that you won't get any repeat delay).

I hope this answer cleared it up for you a little - a little knowledge can lead to great things. Good luck.