# I can't move my Hero with keyboard event

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I can't move my hero with keyboard event, no compiler errors, everything's fine, the only problem is when i press keyboard nothing happen to my hero movement. Here's my code:

```
package
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.events.Event;


public class GameGue extends MovieClip
{
    public var hero:Hero;
    public var speedHero:Number=2;

    public function GameGue()
    {
        hero = new Hero;
        hero.x = 100;
        hero.y = 300;
        addChild(hero);
    }



    public function pencetKeyboard (event:KeyboardEvent):void
    {
        hero.addEventListener (KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, pencetKeyboard);

        if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT)
        {
            hero.x += 2;
            hero.gotoAndStop(3);

        }
    }
}
}
```

And my hero only display frame 1 that show the stand position, not frame 3 that show walk to the right.

EDIT: Another problem: it's my Hero MovieClip when i press RIGHT it is enter frame 3 in my Hero but loop animation in frame 3 forever even when i release the keyboard.

Comment: Before you use the keyboard, click anywhere on the stage to get focus. Does it work then?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. We're not a forum, so we don't edit with the word "solved" in the title. We have an interface for that. Please read the About screen so you know how this community works. http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: If you solved it yourself, post your own answer and accept it when allowed. If you have an additional question, create a new "post" (Question). (You worked off of THIS answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721881/as3-keyboard-control?rq=1 .)

Answer (score 1):

Try moving this line:

```
  hero.addEventListener (KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, pencetKeyboard);
```

just after addChild(hero), inside the GameGue() function.

Comment: Nothing happens, not moving, still standing position on Hero MovieClip frame 1.

Answer (score 0):

Use this one.

```
package
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.events.Event;


public class GameGue extends MovieClip
{
    public var hero:Hero;
    public var speedHero:Number=2;

    public function GameGue()
    {
        hero = new Hero;
        hero.x = 100;
        hero.y = 300;
        addChild(hero);
        stage.addEventListener (KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, pencetKeyboard);

    }



    public function pencetKeyboard (event:KeyboardEvent):void
    {

        if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT)
        {
            hero.x += 2;
            hero.gotoAndStop(3);

        }
    }
}
}
```